# How can I get row-wise indices for elements of vectors in a list which match a certain string in R?

Tags: r, vector

I have a list of vectors which looks something like the following:

```
myList <- list(c("","VNW","SPEC","N","BW" ), c("","WW","N","SPEC","ADJ"),c( "","WW","N"), c("","WW","N"), c("","ADJ","N","WW"), c( "","ADJ","N"))
```

I want to find out which index does the element "N" appear at in each row.
I am not sure what is the best way for the output to look like here. I wouldn't mind it to be an integer vector such as:

```
MyNIndices <- c(4,3,3,3,3,3)
```

or alternatively a list of 6 with one integer element in each list such as:

```
MyNIndices <- list (4,3,3,3,3,3)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `lapply(myList, grep, pattern = "N", fixed = TRUE)` or `lapply(myList, function(x) which(x == "N"))`? Can you show your desired output?

Comment: How about using match `lapply(myList, match, x = "N")`

Comment: @KerryJackson won't return multiple matches, only the first one.

Comment: @KerryJackson I tried this before posting here but it gives me 1 at the position of "N" rather than the numerical value of the indices

Comment: @DavidArenburg has a point that match will only return the first match, but match does not return 1.  It does return a list.  If you unlist, you get a vector `unlist(lapply(myList, match, x = "N"))`

Comment: @KerryJackson you are right. I tried it a different way. I was doing lapply(myList, match,"N")